# Is there any way in the console of seeing where data is going when you click submit on a form on a website?

Tags: jquery, web

Is there any way in the console of seeing where data is going when you click submit on a form on a website?

Comment: Yes, check the 'network' tab. It shows all incoming/outgoing requests. Make sure you check the 'retain data across pages' (or equivalent in whatever browser you use)

Answer (score 2):

I usually using network tab. As far as I know, chrome, mozilla and Internet Explorer have this tab on Inspect Element (mostly F12).
When the website call Ajax or some link, it will show there along with request data and response data.